# Angular - blank page, how to diagnose bootstrapping issues?

Tags: angularjs, bootstrapping

I have a working (in development) Angular app and I've just got my Grunt distribution script working how I want it to, however when run my app through Grunt and then run it from the distribution folder I just get a blank page, no errors, no logging in console, no missing files in the network tab in Chrome etc, it appears everything loads but nothing happens.

I've run into this issue before during development and thrashed around until it worked, however this is now much more complex due to the minified files in distribution etc.

I'd like to properly diagnose this blank page issue but I'm not sure where to start, it appears that Angular is simply not bootstrapping at all after processing to dist mode.

It appears there is no such thing as a very verbose diagnostic mode for Angular, I've switched to the uniminified and there is nothing reported at all.

I checked the minified html file and my ng-app tag is still there on the html element as it should be so that's not the issue.

Also if I drop to console I can type angular and get back the output for it, so it's there, just not doing anything.

Where to start?

Comment: Discovered the solution to my bootstrapping issue was to use the mangle:false option of uglify however that should not be necessary as I'm using Angular's minification safe array method of module reference and it doesn't help to figure out where the actual problem is so this issue still stands.

Answer (score 0):

Start with Chrome devtools open when you load the page.
Add $log.debug statements at the top of all your services and controllers.

app.js will not work without the

```
['paramname1', 'paramname2', function(paramname1, paramname2) {
```

version (all the other files minify fine with out it.)